# How to add an attachment to an email sent from Google App Engine via SendGrid (in Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sendgrid

I followed [Google's information](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sendgrid) to send an email from App Engine via SendGrid. This is working fine using the [Java library for SendGrid](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-google-java) and the provided example code:

```
import packageName.Sendgrid;

Sendgrid mail = new Sendgrid("<sendgrid_username>","<sendgrid_password>");
mail.setTo("foo@bar.com")
    .setFrom("me@bar.com")
    .setSubject("Subject goes here")
    .setText("Hello World!")
mail.send();
```

But now I need to attach an file. How can this be done? I cannot find an `addAttachment`-function or something like that in the [`sendgrid-google-java` library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-google-java).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just use the [SendGrid Java API](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java) on appengine, not a specific google one. 
Here's an example:

```
import com.sendgrid.*;

public class SendGridExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("SENDGRID_APIKEY");

    SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();

    email.addTo("test@sendgrid.com");
    email.setFrom("you@youremail.com");
    email.setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
    email.setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");

    SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
  }
}
```

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/java.html

You can add attachments to this email object using either one of these 3 functions:

```
    public Email addAttachment(String name, File file) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        return this.addAttachment(name, new FileInputStream(file));
    }

    public Email addAttachment(String name, String file) throws IOException {
        return this.addAttachment(name, new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()));
    }

    public Email addAttachment(String name, InputStream file) throws IOException {
        this.attachments.put(name, file);
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: This works out of the box? What's the purpose of the [`sendgrid-google-java` library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-google-java) then? I'll try out and report back.

Comment: Using the normal SendGrid Java API directly was the right recommendation, thanks+. However, the example code did not work for me (maybe because they switched the API version?). I'll add the working code as an answer.

Comment: If you check the github page for sendgrid-google-java, you can see it hasn't been updated for 2 years, so I wouldn't use it either way. It could indeed be the case that my code was an older API. I'm glad you've got it working!

Answer (score 2):

Sending email from GAE using [sendgrid-java](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java) is working as [suggested by Serge Hendrickx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39794166/2306907).
Just for reference, here is the code I ended up using (with the latest `sendgrid-java.jar`):

```
public static Mail buildAttachmentEmailExample(String fileName, String base64EncodedFileContent, String contentType) throws IOException {

    Mail mail = new Mail();
    Personalization pers = new Personalization();

    Email from = new Email("test@example.com");
    mail.setFrom(from); 

    String subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid Java Library";
    pers.setSubject(subject);

    Email to = new Email("test@example.com");
    pers.addTo(to);
    Email cc = new Email("test2@example.com");
    pers.addCc(cc);

    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "some text here");
    mail.addContent(content);

    Attachments attachments = new Attachments();
    attachments.setContent(base64EncodedFileContent);
    attachments.setType(contentType);
    attachments.setFilename(fileName);
    mail.addAttachments(attachments);

    mail.addPersonalization(pers);
    return mail;
}

public static void sendMail(Mail mail) throws IOException {
    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("SENDGRID_API_KEY");

    Request request = new Request();
    try {
      request.method = Method.POST;
      request.endpoint = "mail/send";
      request.body = mail.build();
      Response response = sg.api(request);
      System.out.println(response.statusCode);
      System.out.println(response.body);
      System.out.println(response.headers);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
}

public static void test() throws IOException {

    Mail mail = buildAttachmentEmailExample("test.txt", "WW91IGhhdmUgdG9vIG11Y2ggdGltZSE=", "text/plain");
    sendMail(mail);
}
```

The code is based on the examples at https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/Example.java and utilizes the newer SendGrid v3 API.

Comment: A useful way to base64 encode your attachment content is Apache Commons Codec <https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/> and Apache Commons IO <http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/> in this way, `Base64 x = new Base64(); attachments.setContent(x.encodeAsString(IOUtils.toByteArray((InputStream) content)));`